# How to import existing OpenSsl project into Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, openssl

I would like to modify the existing Openssl project. So I downloaded the source code of openssl from GitHub https://github.com/openssl/openssl
and follow the instruction http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Easy-inclusion-of-OpenSSL-into-iOS-projects-agileinfoways-com-td48905.html on how to include Openssl into Xcode.

However, when i tried to build one of the file (enc.c) from OpenSsl project, it run into 6 errors and 7 warning.

```
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ecdsa.h
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:295:14: Parameter
'flags' not found in the function declaration
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:301:14: Parameter                

'ecdsa_method' not found in the function declaration
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ecdsa.h:302:14: Parameter 'name'    not found in the function declaration

/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/apps.h
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/apps.h:421:1: Unknown type name '__owur'
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/apps.h:421:8: Expected identifier or '('
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/apps.h:432:1: Unknown type name '__owur'
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/apps.h:432:8: Expected identifier or '('
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/progs.h
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/progs.h:25:1: Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'

/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/enc.c
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/enc.c:542:47: Expected ')'
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/enc.c:543:47: Expected ')'
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/enc.c:427:33: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/enc.c:597:28: Implicit declaration of function 'OPENSSL_hexchar2int' is invalid in C99
/Users/maggie/Documents/aes/openssl-master/apps/enc.c:582:9: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'
```

Source code of enc.c is [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/enc.c)

Does anyone ever encounter this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to Configure the library using OpenSSL's `Configure` script. It produces the various [recursive] Makefiles, and platform specific headers, like `opensslconf.h` and `bn.h`. After you configure, you should build with `make`. If you choose not to, then its your job to setup the project up correctly, including the same `#defines`. `enc.c` is part of the `openssl` target, and not the `libcrypto` or `libssl` targets. You should inspect the makefile's produced by OpenSSL `Configure`, and then translate them into Xcode.

Comment: @jww, Thanks for the pointer. I Configured library using OpenSsl Configure script.  After configure, I built with `Make`. The Make ran without any error message so I assumed it is successfully built and installed. After that I added /usr/local/include folder to `User Header Search Path`  and drag /usr/local/bin/openssl to `Link Binary with Library` in Xcode. It still ran into errors of missing header files. Then I manually drag those missing header files into the project and it ran into `Apple Mach-O Linker Error`. Do i missing any step?

Comment: You want the libraries `libssl.a` and `libcrypo.a`; ***not*** `openssl`. `openssl` is the executable. `libssl.a` and `libcrypo.a` are the SSL and Crypto libraries, respectively.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks again!